# Crystal Reports migration

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I want to upgrade my .NET application built under .NET Framework 3.5 to 4.0. It uses crystal reports that comes within vs 2008 and I now want to use crystal reports runtime for VS 2010. Could it create any issues?

Comment: From my experience, I didn't had any issues related to Crystal Reports by upgrading from VS 2008 to VS 2010, but it's always a good idea to backup your project before doing any upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The only issues you'll have are the random bugs from different runtime engines. For example, the 2010 (2011) engine randomly has issues with XLS exports. The executable running the runtime just stops working.

Other that, no, there are no issues.